# How to add an icon/image at the end of each list item in html/css?

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

Need to make following layout properly using html and css. It is a side block list/menu.

#### Recent Searches

- Nick Cave and the Bad Seeds
- African Animals

[image]

i tried using span on image and floating it right but it comes below the li text

Comment: where is the following layout?

Comment: please show us some code